# Context not passed to overwritten templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-auth-ldap

Django version 3.2.4

I'm trying to change the default `index_title`, `site_header`, and `site_title` used by the admin site.  I've tried all the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938491/django-admin-change-header-django-administration-text), but the login page refuses to use the updated values.  In fact, the required context (`site_header` in the example below) is empty (confirmed by overriding the template and using the `{{ debug }}` variable as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066905/how-do-i-get-all-the-variables-defined-in-a-django-template)) and the "default" value of "Django administration" is being used.  A line from the template `C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base_site.html`:

```
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }} a</a></h1>
```

I currently have all three variables overwritten in my app's `admin.py` file, and the updated values are being used after I've logged in, but it doesn't work on the initial login page:

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My Site Header'
admin.site.index_title = 'My Index Title'
admin.site.site_title = 'My Site Title'
```

I can override the `base_site.html` template and hardcode a value, but I would like to understand why that is necessary and figure out how I can pass some context to that overwritten template.  I've tried all the methods of overriding the original context described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) to no avail.  That includes having a [custom admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class) which [overrides the default admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site).  I've also noticed that the [each_context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.each_context) method is not being called on the initial login page, but it is called after I have logged in and I'm viewing an admin page.

I think some of the problem may stem from how I have my `urlpatterns` set up in `urls.py`.  I have it set up like this so the URL displayed in the address bar for a login is the same for both the admin and non-admin portions of the site.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('my_app.urls')),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='admin/login.html')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='admin/login.html')),
    path('logout', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('admin/login', generic_views.RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin', permanent=True, query_string=False)),
    path('admin/login/', generic_views.RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin', permanent=True, query_string=False)),
    path('admin/logout', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('admin/logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

I'm also exclusively using the `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend'
]
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did also make your custom admin site the default admin site? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site

Comment: Yes, I performed the steps in both the "Customizing" and "Overriding" sections.

Answer (score 0):

I got around my problem by creating the following context processor:

```
from django.contrib import admin


def global_context(request):
    """
    This is intended to be a global context processor.  Any templates rendered from views using the
    `django.template.RequestContext` context (the default context used by generic views) will have this context
    available to them.
    """

    context = {
        'index_title': admin.site.index_title,
        'site_header': admin.site.site_header,
        'site_title': admin.site.site_title
    }

    return context
```

This in conjunction with setting `admin.site.index_title`, `admin.site.site_header`, and `admin.site.site_title` to the desired values in `admin.py` got things working as expected.